# Oauth2 - Parsing token always throwing exception

Tags: oauth

I am trying to parse a token this way:

```
        Claims claims1 = Jwts.parser() 
                   .setSigningKey( publicKey)
                   .parseClaimsJws( token);
```

But I always get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures.  Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
```

Nonetheless, when I try the same token with my public and ***private key*** in https://jwt.io/ , it is validated. Two questions:

1. Is it necessary to specify the private key? If so, how could I do so in my code?
2. In fact right now I do not care about signature validation -for sure in the future. For the moment I would be happy with an answer on just how to parse the token without validating it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `publicKey` is Base64-encoded String.
In that case you need to decode it and create an instance of `sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl`:

```java
byte[] decode = TextCodec.BASE64.decode(publicKey);
Key key = new RSAPublicKeyImpl(decode);
Claims claims1 = Jwts.parser() 
               .setSigningKey(key)
               .parseClaimsJws(token);
```